# Rails routes and controller actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

In my controller I have -

```
def remove_file
  @chap_comment.remove_chap_comment_pdf!
  @chap_comment.save
end
```

... and in my view I have -

```
<%= link_to 'remove pdf', controller: 'chap_comments', action: 'remove_file', id: comment.id %>
```

... in routes.rb I simply have -

resources :chap_comments

... but before the page with the link in even renders I'm getting `No route matches {:action=>"remove_file", :controller=>"chap_comments", :id=>1}` - what should I be putting in my routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `member`:

```
  resources :chap_comments do
    member do
      delete 'remove_file'
    end
  end
```

This adds an extra resource path for `remove_file`. The full path would be `remove_file_chap_comment_path`.

Comment: `get 'remove_file'` seems to work, but `delete` doesn't, or at least not for me - should I edit the answer?

Comment: You can use whichever HTTP verb you like but it looks like your `remove_file` action is attempting to delete something so ideally you would use DELETE. Have you tried calling the route with `remove_file_chap_comment_path(id)`?

Comment: I get `No route matches [GET] "/chap_comments/id/remove_file"'` so I figured it was expecting a get. The link_to I've used is `link_to 'remove pdf', remove_file_chap_comment_path(:id)`

Comment: Try supplying the `:method => :delete` option to your `link_to`. If you don't specify it will default to GET

Comment: Thanks Tom. That calls the action correctly,but out of interest, what does rails do with the delete method?

Comment: Glad that helped :). Rails just matches the `link_to` method to the correct route. So you could have two different `remove_file` routes: one GET and one DELETE. The corresponding controller action methods can contain any code you like but HTTP GETs should only request data, if you are deleting a record you should use HTTP DELETE

Answer (score 1):

You need to add route for remove_file in your routes file. like below:

```
get "chap_comments/:id/remove_file" => 'chap_comments#remove_file'
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your routes like

```
resources :chap_comments do
  member do
    delete :remove_file
  end
end
```

Then you can make a link (run `rake routes` to see the full path name to method)

```
= link_to "Remove PDF", remove_file_chap_comment_path(id), :method => :delete
```